# Create process tree form json file. in python

Tags: python, json, process, treeview

I need some assistance on a somewhat simple issue.

I'm trying to convert the content of a json file from this:

```
    {   "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "SVCHOST.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": SVCHOST.EXE,
        "Pid": "876",
        "PPID": "500"],
        "children": [Process details])
    },
    {   "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
        "name": "LSAS.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
        "Pid": "500",
        "PPID": "4"],
        "children": [Process details])
    },
    {   "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
        "name": "SYSTEM",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "SYSTEM",
        "Pid": "4",
        "PPID": "0"],
        "children": [Process details])
    }
```

To this:

```
{
"name": "Root", 
"children": [
    {
        "name": "4", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "500", 
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "876", 
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To create a node tree graph in the end.

But after a lot of trial and error, and still not close to the output I need. I'm asking for some pointer, tips or tricks.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Here is my most recent attempt.

```
import json

links = ({
"Timestamp": "Timestamp",
    "name": "SVCHOST.EXE",
    "icon": "binary_icon.png",
    "Process": "SVCHOST.EXE",
    "Pid": "876",
    "PPID": "500",
    "children": "Process_details"
},
  {
    "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
    "name": "LSAS.EXE",
    "icon": "binary_icon.png",
    "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
    "Pid": "500",
    "PPID": "4",
    "children": "Process_details"
},
  {
    "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
    "name": "SYSTEM",
    "icon": "binary_icon.png",
    "Process": "SYSTEM",
    "Pid": "4",
    "PPID": "0",
    "children": "Process_details"
})



parent_proc_node = {}
root = {'name': 'Root', 'children': []}
for item in procs:
    parent_node = parent_proc_node.get(item['Pid'])
    if not parent_node:
        parent_proc_node[item['Pid']] = parent_node = {'name': item['PPID']}
        root['children'].append(parent_node)
    parent_proc_node[item['PPID']] = child_node = {'name': item['Pid']}
    parent_node.setdefault('children', []).append(child_node)

print json.dumps(root, indent=4)
```

Current output:

```
{
"name": "Root", 
"children": [
    {
        "name": "500", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "876", 
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "500", 
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "4"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The output is now what I want, but im still not able to correctly match parent process with children.
What am I doing wrong?

The correct output would be like this:

```
{
"name": "Root", 
"children": [
    {
        "name": "4", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "500", 
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "876", 
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input & output data look a bit odd. Eg, the `]` after the "PPID" don't look correct. What happened to the matching `[`?

Comment: Sorry thats my bad, I had to remove some system sensitive info, from the json file.

Comment: Ok, but you need to fix the sample data so that it's valid. That makes it easier to understand exactly what you want to do, and it makes it easier for people to test their solution code.

Comment: Ok, so Im getting a bit closer.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help us to answer your question. There are now two different incompatible versions of the input data, and two different desired outputs. I think I know what you're trying to do, but there's not much point in me posting code that won't handle your actual data. Also, it's not clear why you want each of the "children" items to be a list containing a dictionary. Why don't you just nest the dictionary directly inside  "children" instead of wrapping it in a list?

Comment: It might be not displaying the issue properly. the attached code is working, and the json is correct, except for the fact, that is not matching the processes parent  and child relation. Not sure what you mean? 
A parent process can have multiple child processes, and these children, can also have children..

Comment: In the data you posted each parent only has a single child. The answer I posted works correctly with such data. If you need to handle parents having multiple children your sample data needs to reflect that.

Comment: That is the case, true, but thats only a snippet of the entire json file.
Basically my json is a full procdump, of a running windows.
And the task at hand is to visually represent the process parent child and potential grandchildren, in a tree graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that does what I *think* you want. It processes the `links` (which I turned into a list, since JSON doesn't have tuples), converting it into the nested structure that you show as the final correct output. I've also added a couple of new records so that some parents have multiple children.

The trick is to first create a dictionary (`ids`) that captures the parent-child relationship of the process IDs.

```
import json

links = [
    {
        "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "SVCHOST.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "SVCHOST.EXE",
        "Pid": "876",
        "PPID": "500",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "LSAS.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
        "Pid": "500",
        "PPID": "4",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "LSAS.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
        "Pid": "510",
        "PPID": "4",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "LSAS.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
        "Pid": "600",
        "PPID": "510",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "SYSTEM",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "SYSTEM",
        "Pid": "4",
        "PPID": "0",
        "children": "Process_details"
    }
]

# Create a dict linking each pid to its parent
ids = {}
for d in links:
    # Use "0" as the ppid if "PPID" field is an empty string 
    ppid, pid = d["PPID"] or "0", d["Pid"]
    ids.setdefault(ppid, []).append(pid)
print(ids)

# Nest the data for each pid in its parent's dict
def insert(lst, ppid, name):
    if ppid in ids:
        children = []
        lst.append({"name": name, "children": children})
        for pid in ids[ppid]:
            insert(children, pid, pid)
    else:
        children = [{"name": ""}]
        lst.append({"name": name, "children": children})

nested = []
insert(nested, "0", "Root")
print(json.dumps(nested[0], indent=4))
```

**output**

```
{'500': ['876'], '4': ['500', '510'], '510': ['600'], '0': ['4']}
{
    "name": "Root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "4",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "876",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "510",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "600",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost does the trick :) 
Now only remaining issue is that, calling insert function, with a prefix pid, will not work.
When I run the above code, on the sample date, only the process children for PPID 0 is nested.

Comment: @Jmik I don't know what you mean by "prefix pid". The `insert` function relies on the structure in the `ids` dict being a connected tree, and you need to call `insert` with  the root node of that tree. If you have multiple trees, then you'll need to do a little more work to deal with that.

Comment: in your snippet, `code´insert(nested, "0", "Root") `code´ PPID is 0. This means, if the json date do not contain the PID 0, your function, will not populate the process tree.

Comment: {u'2060': [u'2120'], u'2120': [u'2208'], None: [u'2060']}
{
    "children": {
        "icon": "binary_icon.png", 
        "name": "PPID", 
        "children": []
    }, 
    "name": "win10", 
    "icon": "win_os_icon.png"
}

As you can see form the above, PPID 0 do not exits, and therefore function breaks.

Answer (score 0):

@PM 2Ring Sorry please disregard the PPID 0 remarks. missing execution handling at my end. :)
Your excample works perfectly, for parents with child pids. however if a PID has no parent it is not added to the root node.

```
procs = [{
  "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
        "name": "SVCHOST.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "SVCHOST.EXE",
        "Pid": "876",
        "PPID": "500",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
      {
        "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
        "name": "LSAS.EXE",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "LSAS.EXE",
        "Pid": "500",
        "PPID": "4",
        "children": "Process_details"
    },
      {
        "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
        "name": "SYSTEM",
        "icon": "binary_icon.png",
        "Process": "SYSTEM",
        "Pid": "4",
        "PPID": "0",
        "children": "Process_details"
}
,
  {
    "Timestamp":"Timestamp",
    "name": "ROUGEPROC",
    "icon": "binary_icon.png",
    "Process": "ROUGEPROC",
    "Pid": "4322",
    "PPID": "",
    "children": "Process_details"
}]

# Create a dict linking each pid to its parent
ids = {}
for d in procs:
    ppid, pid = d["PPID"], d["Pid"]
    ids.setdefault(ppid, []).append(pid)
print(ids)

# Nest the data for each pid in its parent's dict
def insert(lst, ppid, name):
    if ppid in ids:
        children = []
        lst.append({"name": name, "children": children, "icon": "binary_icon.png"})
        for pid in ids[ppid]:
            insert(children, pid, pid)
    else:
        children = []
        lst.append({"name": name, "children": children, "icon": "binary_icon.png"})

nested = []

insert(nested, "0", "PPID")
proc_report = {"name" :"HOSTNAME",
                        "icon": "win_os_icon.png",
                         "children": nested[0]["children"]
                         }
print(json.dumps(proc_report, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{'': ['4322'], '0': ['4'], '4': ['500'], '500': ['876']}
{
    "children": [
        {
            "icon": "binary_icon.png", 
            "name": "4", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "icon": "binary_icon.png", 
                    "name": "500", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "icon": "binary_icon.png", 
                            "name": "876", 
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "name": "HOSTNAME", 
    "icon": "win_os_icon.png"
}
```

Comment: "if a PID has no parent it is not added to the root node." That's easy enough to deal with. If in the `for d in links:` loop the "PPID" field is "" then convert it to "0", eg `ppid, pid = d["PPID"] or "0", d["Pid"]`

Comment: very true, and working :) And thanks for the assistance / patience, been starring myself blind on this the last couple of days.